# Json Tableview Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, nsdictionary

this post follows an old post where some people helped me for a similar problem.

I currently developing an app which list user object by making an request to a webservice, which send a response in JSON in this format :

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "id": "28",
        "title": "test",
        "price": "56 €",
        "description": "kiki",
        "addedDate": "11-07-2015",
        "user_id": "1",
        "user_name": "CANOVAS",
        "user_zipCode": "69330",
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_label": "VEHICULES",
        "subcategory_id": "1",
        "subcategory_label": "Voitures",
        "picture": "",
        "bdd": {},
        "picture_url": "http://jdl-barreme-orange.dyndns.org/WEBSERVICE/pictures/test.JPG"
    },
    {
        "id": "27",
        "title": "ferrari",
        "price": "55 €",
        "description": "rouge jantes",
        "addedDate": "11-07-2015",
        "user_id": "1",
        "user_name": "CANOVAS",
        "user_zipCode": "69330",
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_label": "VEHICULES",
        "subcategory_id": "1",
        "subcategory_label": "Voitures",
        "picture": "",
        "bdd": {},
        "picture_url": "http://jdl-barreme-orange.dyndns.org/WEBSERVICE/pictures/ferrari.JPG"
    }
}
```

I search a method to retrieve for each dictionary the value title and price and put them in a tableView.

**Code I used (tableviewcontroller) :**

```
if let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
for dict in jsonArray {
    if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
        println(title)
    }
}
}
```

But it doesn't work, I put a breakpoint, and Xcode stop to interpret here :

```
for dict in jsonArray
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example JSON is not valid: it lacks a `]` before the last `}`.

But I guess this is just a pasting typo and the JSON you're using is properly formatted, so your problem is that you need to first access the `objects` key of your dictionary.

This key holds a value of an array of dictionaries, so we're using it as a typecast:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let objects = json["objects"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        for dict in objects {
            if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
                println(title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First we cast the result of `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` as the dictionary: `[String:AnyObject]`, then we access the value for the `objects` key, then we cast this value as an array of dictionaries: `[[String:AnyObject]]`.

Remember, with JSON format, dictionaries are formatted with `{}` and arrays are formatted with `[]`.

Your example is `{key:[{},{}]}` so it's a dictionary holding an array of dictionaries.

---

**Update for Swift 2.0**

```
if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let objects = json?["objects"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        for dict in objects {
            if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
                print(title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: of course it was a pasting error. Thank you again, it works now. Your explanations are very clear, i think to be able to resolve some of theses problems alone now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
   var DataFromJSon = jsonResult["objects"] as! NSArray
        for one in DataFromJSon {
          var title = one["title"] as! String 
           println(title)

       }
```

Comment: welcome man ... you just need to pay attention to those **[** and **{** so you could know if you need to go a step further to extract the data .